# .Net Core: Is there a HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError switch?

Tags: c#, .net-core, out-of-memory, dump

In java there's the possibility to generate a dump when a OutOfMemoryError is raised. See [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html). This is really useful because for debugging memory leaks, because it shows many of your leaking instances.

Does a similar mechanism exist for .NET Core?

Comment: Not sure if you can. Though this fairly reactive, ideally you would proactively profile your app, if you are getting out of memory exceptions in c# 9 times out of 10 you aren't out of memory, however you likely doing something inherently unsafe like loading billions of items into arrays, running out of gdi memory or something else which likely shouldn't be done. Additionally when these errors happen they are pointing to exact place where the problem is. Once again, this should have been discovered in development with profiling

Comment: Not as part of the runtime itself. The usual approach would be to use some native mechanism to do a full memory dump on a process crash, like `procdump` on Windows (there's doubtlessly something equivalent for Linux, though I don't know what).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would accept this comment, if it was an answer...